# derby system tables for the column of primary key info

Tags: derby

I'm trying to retrieve the columns for PK from system tables and looking through the documentation I cannot see how I can get that information. SYS.SYSCONSTRAINTS does not contain column information.

I want to know which column belong to for the primary key. I find the tables in sys schema then I can get all the primary key info. The SQL is:

```sql
select t.tablename,
conglomeratename backIdxName,
cst.constraintname,
cst.type
from sys.systables   t,
sys.sysconstraints   cst,
sys.sysconglomerates cgl,
sys.syskeys          sk
where isindex = 'TRUE'
and cgl.tableid = t.tableid
and (sk.constraintid = cst.constraintid and cst.type = 'P' and
sk.conglomerateid = cgl.conglomerateid)
and t.tableid = cst.tableid
and t.tabletype = 'T'
```

all the primary key is query out, but I wanna know the relation between primary key and column. I don't know which the column belong to for the primary key. I find sys.syscolumns table but nothing useful.

anybody know it ?

thanks.

Comment: Are you trying to automate this? Or you just want to explore the schema of an existing database? I find it much easier to use a tool like IJ or dblook or SquirrelSQL to explore the database schema interactively.

Comment: I'm trying to retrieve the columns for constraints (PK, FK, unique, check) from system tables and looking through the documentation I cannot see how I can get that information. SYS.SYSCONSTRAINTS does not contain column information.