# Describe table to get the primary key for a table in Apache Derby

Tags: primary-key, derby

I am using Apache Derby 10.14.2. I need to know the primary key for a table. When I perform the Describe for the table, I only got the following instruction. 
[derby system tables for the column of primary key info](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20396376/derby-system-tables-for-the-column-of-primary-key-info) do not have an answer.

```
ij> create table id ( id int primary key, name varchar(10));
ij> describe id; 

COLUMN_NAME         |TYPE_NAME|DEC&|NUM&|COLUM&|COLUMN_DEF|CHAR_OCTE&|IS_NULL&
------------------------------------------------------------------------------
ID                  |INTEGER  |0   |10  |10    |NULL      |NULL      |YES     
NAME                |VARCHAR  |NULL|NULL|10    |NULL      |20        |YES
```

In this, no information about the primary key is given. What is the query to get the primary key of a table in Apache Derby?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In a program, use [DatabaseMetaData.getPrimaryKeys()](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/sql/DatabaseMetaData.html#getPrimaryKeys(java.lang.String,%20java.lang.String,%20java.lang.String))

Or, if you want to run queries against the Derby system catalogs directly, you can read the answers to [this related question](https://stackoverflow.com/q/845766/193453).